Are Jobs Involving Video Editing for Influencers Haram?
Is working for a social media influencer or YouTuber nowadays considered haram in Islam? Specifically, if you edit their videos (excluding any 18+ content but including music videos featuring both men and women), would this be impermissible? There are thousands of people who edit YouTube and Instagram reels for their clients. So, is this haram income?

Understanding its philosophy will help you more. In the matter of sexual issues, the philosophy of Islam is that a human being needs marriage and this need should not be fulfilled in other ways. Therefore, because such content causes people to stray from the path of marriage or fall into sin (masturbation or adultery, etc.), Muslims are prohibited from doing such things as much as possible. So jobs that involve video editing for influencers are not a bad thing in themselves and the money is fine, but what matters is the video. Does this video lead you or others to sin or further away from God?
